How to update streamlit elements using JS
I am trying to create a streamlit app which has multiple expanders. For testing purposes each container needs a id tag that I can use. I am completely new to JS and this was my solution that I came up with.
My understanding of the problem is that streamlit does not load the content when the JS script runs. The log shows that body element of the document is completely empty.
Any idea how i should address this?
My attempt
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

# Create sample dataframes
data1 = {'Column 1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Column 2': [10, 20, 30, 40]}
data2 = {'Column A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'Column B': ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']}
data3 = {'Column X': [100, 200, 300, 400], 'Column Y': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

# Create expanders with specific IDs
expanders = [
    {"title": "Expander 1", "dataframe": df1, "id": "expander-unique-id-1"},
    {"title": "Expander 2", "dataframe": df2, "id": "expander-unique-id-2"},
    {"title": "Expander 3", "dataframe": df3, "id": "expander-unique-id-3"},
]

for expander in expanders:
    with st.expander(expander["title"], expanded=True):
        st.dataframe(expander["dataframe"])

# Inject JavaScript to set custom unique IDs for each expander
components.html(f"""
<script>
    // Wait for the Streamlit app to load the expander elements 
    
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){{setTimeout(assignIds, 3000)}});

    function assignIds() {{
        const expanders = {len(expanders)};
        const ids = {str([exp["id"] for exp in expanders])};
        var expander_list = document.querySelectorAll('stExpander');
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll('html'))
        for (let i = 0; i < expanders; i++) {{
            const expander = expander_list[i];
            if (expander) {{
                expander.id = ids[i];
                console.log("Expander with unique ID set:", expander);
            }}
        }}

    }}
</script>
""", height=0)

st.write("Expanders wrapped with unique IDs for tracking.")


I believe that Streamlit's HTML components do not directly support such manipulation. The way we could workaround this issue is maybe by- Checking the correct query selector, since Streamlit elements are often rendered inside shadow DOMs, which makes direct selection tricky. You might need to use more specific selectors.
Also, Ensure the script runs after the Streamlit elements are fully loaded since using setTimeout might not be reliable.
Here's a few changes I feel can solve the issue:
Replace:
window.addEventListener("load", function(){{setTimeout(assignIds, 3000)}});

With:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {....

AND
Replace:
var expander_list = document.querySelectorAll('stExpander');

With:
var expander_list = document.querySelectorAll('details');

I basically used  DOMContentLoaded to ensure the script runs after the DOM is fully loaded and Changed the query selector to 'details', which is the HTML element used by Streamlit for expanders.

Hey I tried this. the loading of content in shadow DOMs is throwing me off.
I was able to do this id injection using this code that I found on streamlit discussion forums.
https://gist.github.com/scanzy/e6c2a75894affc7245fc93fa33a09c74
